# Why this simple code is giving syntax error?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, decltype

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void fun(int i)
{
    cout<<"Called with int "<<i;
}

void main()
{
    using df = decltype(&fun);
}
```

I am getting following syntax errors in Visual Studio,

```
Error   1   error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '='  c:\users\kpranit\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\sample\sample\sample.cpp 12

Error   2   error C2873: 'df' : symbol cannot be used in a using-declaration    c:\users\kpranit\documents\visual studio 2012\projects\sample\sample\sample.cpp 12
```

Comment: Looks like that version of the compiler is too old.  Try the latest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 which, based on your project directory, is the one you're using, does not support type aliasing.

It's a C++11 feature and does not make an appearance in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e6a4at9.aspx), even for VS2013, though I think that may just be a doc error on their part - the [Microsoft site for C++11 compatibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh567368.aspx) (look for "alias templates") lists it as being available under VS2013.

So, if you want to use that feature, you'll probably have to upgrade to the later compiler.